# Findcontrol Listview Edit - NullreferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a rather odd problem. I have an editable ListView, however - when I click edit I usually get the NullreferenceException once I try to get the textboxes. BUT the error is not consistent, sometimes it is there, sometimes not. I'm confused.

This is the code snippit:

```
public void test_ItemEditing(Object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
{

    // Liest die SpeiseID mit der die Daten aus der Datenbank extrahiert werden können
    DataKey currentDataKey = speiseplanListView.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex];

    TextBox editDatum  = (TextBox)speiseplanListView.EditItem.FindControl("txtDatum");


}
```

this is the asp.net file:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtDatum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSpeise" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

    </tr>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Which event is test_ItemEditing bound to?

Comment: <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="speiseplanListView" OnItemEditing="test_ItemEditing" DataKeyNames="Speise_ID" >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your `test_ItemEditing` code with below one

```
public void test_ItemEditing(Object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    lvEmployee.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    test.DataSource = GetData("Select * from Table");

    test.DataBind();
}
```

and handle the `test_ItemUpdating` event for finding the control and updating the data.

Comment: The row loads the content and I do not get an exception but unfortunately the row is not displayed in textboxes - but as usual labels ( like in the "non-edit" event).

Comment: Bind text box value in edititem template e.g.<asp:TextBox ID="txtDatum" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Datum") %>'></asp:TextBox>