# Object Not Set to an Instance of an Object Error: ListView EditItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am trying to get an edit item from the list view inside the `ItemEditing` event handler. When I try to get the control using this code:

```
TextBox JobDesTextBox = (TextBox)(LV_Tickets.EditItem.FindControl("JobDescTextBox"));
```

I get the error `Object is not set to an instance of an object`. I know that the JobDescTextBox exists in the EditItem template because I use it in the `ItemCanceling` event. I am thinking that possibly it is throwing this error because the control does not exist at this point in time of the website, but I am not sure how to work around this. This is the snippet from the `EditItemTemplate` in the ListView:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="JobDescTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("JobDesc") %>' />
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at his link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152630/findcontrol-listview-edit-nullreferenceexception

Comment: Alright, I tried what that guy suggested, but when I try to set the text of the textbox it does not work. There are no errors thrown, but it does not set it.

Comment: can you show the code that you are using to depict what you have just stated..so that we can see..?

Comment: I actually just fixed it. I had to put the line `e.Cancel = true` so the textbox would not get the value that the database is supplying.

Comment: so it sounds like you corrected your issue then.. [MSDN ListView.EditItem Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.edititem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) some good reference material for future use

Comment: Yes I did! Thank you for the suggested reading. Been on this for a while.

Answer (score 1):

After @MethodMan's post I was able to fix my problem. I set the edit index to the correct one and re-binded the list view.

```
LV_Tickets.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
LV_Tickets.DataBind();
```

In order to set the textbox value and not get the value that is stored in the database I had to cancel the edit event using `e.Cancel = true;`

the final code looked like this:

```
LV_Tickets.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
LV_Tickets.DataBind();
e.Cancel = true;
TextBox JobDesTextBox = (TextBox)(LV_Tickets.EditItem.FindControl("JobDescTextBox"));
JobDesTextBox.Text = "Setting the textbox";
```